# How to purify/treat air smell produced by a kitchen?

Tags: air-quality, drain-waste-vent

[image: Kitchen]

Ignore the ugly look.

Sometimes I cooked food with very strong smell. That smell sometimes is not expected by many neighbors, they protested. Rather than to use exhaust fan, I considered to install funnel on top of the stove, then I will pipe it to the roof. I expected it will send the air-smell high enough. But, learned from another neighbor, that way is still not solve the problem. The air-smell sometimes is still there, especially when wind blows, the smell went anywhere. It considered become pollutant. Then, I was thinking how to solve. What is the best way to treat that air-smell?

Is any method how to treat that smell so it become neutral (or "clean") before it "delivered" the the free air? Just consider like water-waste treatment of any industry, it must treated before released to the nature/river. I expected that there is one device which such the smell, and proceed until it clean, and then deliver to the air.

Comment: I would have suggested an extended height outlet and active carbon filters as a start, but you seemed to reject forced ventilation solutions in your question...

Comment: Learned from neighbor, roof is about 5 meter above and 1m more extra rotating exhaust. The smell is still there. If I have to extend another 5m, I doubt that it will solve the problem. But your advice about active carbon fiber, that is interesting. What is it about?

Comment: I suspect the real problem here has more to do with societal interactions than the odors *per se* .   If they have religious objections to smells, I have zero sympathy for them and neither should you.   But if you choose, there are all sorts of filter systems, and none of them will work without a forcing fan somewhere to guide the effluvium properly.

Comment: There more and more tension nowadays. That probably just a camuflage or it just their way to trigger conflict so they have justification to force whatever they want. I believe you know many things happen around the world like that. And probably your country is starting suffering such case. Hard core is rising so fast in my places. So now tell me what I should do. Life must go on, isn't it?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft There are some dishes to where the neighbors may be right to complain: https://www.delish.com/food/news/a38906/top-ten-stinky-foods-durian-natto/

Comment: In our case, it is fully due to religion objection.